# How come my condition determining if a user is in a group always returns as false?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm writing a script that requires detecting if the executing user account is a domain admin. I do this by getting the current user and checking if they are in the Domain Admins security group.

```
#Get current user
$CurrentUser = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name | Out-String
$CurrentUser = $CurrentUser -replace 'DOMAIN\\' 

#Get list of Domain Admins members
$DomainAdmins = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins" -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | Out-String

#Relevant condition
If ($DomainAdmins -like ($CurrentUser)) {
     Write-Output "You're a domain admin." #example
}
Else {
     Write-Output "You're not a domain admin."
}
```

Without fail, this script always runs the `Else` code when run from our domain controller using a domain administrator account.

I have also tried using `-contains` and `.contains()` with the exact same results. I've verified that the `$CurrentUser` value represents the current user accurately and that `$DomainAdmins` lists out the expected list of users.

I can also do this:

```
if ($DomainAdmins -contains ("USERNAME")) {Write-host "true"}
```

Where `USERNAME` is the current user typed out directly (case-correct or not) and it correctly returns true when that user is a member of the group.

Comment: can you try with `.Contains(...)` instead. From the docs, `-contains` operator tells whether a collection of reference values includes a single test value. In other words, it is looking for a collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$userSID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User.Value

$DomainAdmins = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins" -Recursive

if($DomainAdmins.SID.Contains($userSID))
{
     Write-Output "You're a domain admin."
}
...

# OR 

if($userSID -in $DomainAdmins.SID)
{
     Write-Output "You're a domain admin."
}
...

# OR

if($DomainAdmins.SID -contains $userSID)
{
    Write-Output "You're a domain admin."
}
```

The `Out-String` on `Get-ADGroupMember` is converting your `array` into a `string` which is why you can't use it as comparison:

```
PS /> @(
    'one'
    'two'
    'three'
) -contains 'one'
True

PS /> (@(
    'one'
    'two'
    'three'
) | Out-String) -contains 'one'
False
```

---

An alternative, instead of using `Get-ADGroupMember`:

```
$userSID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User.Value

$domainAdminsDN = (Get-ADGroup -Identity "Domain Admins").DistinguishedName
$recursiveMembers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$domainAdminsDN)"

if($recursiveMembers.SID.Contains($userSID))
{
    Write-Output "You're a domain admin."
}
...
...
```

Comment: Used your first solution and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @VictorArevalo happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way to do this is by checking the `MemberOf` property of the user. It works a little better to keep them as AD objects when you have multiple domains or other oddities:

```
# check if DA
$DAdn = (Get-ADGroup 'Domain Admins').distinguishedname
If ( Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(SamAccountName=$Env:USERNAME)(MemberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$DAdn))" ) {
    Write-Output "You're a domain admin." #example
}
```

Your `$DomainAdmins` variable is a single string with the members instead of a list object. Using `... | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName` is enough to get your list without `Out-String`.

Comment: He is checking recursively though, this would not produce the desired output if the user is a member of a group nested in Domain Admins.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Whoops, I missed it! I've updated my answer to do a recursive search.

Answer (score 0):

`-contains` Looks for exact matches in collections, not for substrings.

You have to either remove `Out-String` from `$DomainAdmins`, to make it a list and make sure that the name matches entirely, or use `.Contains(...)` to look for a substring inside the `$DomainAdmins` string